# Position a bootstrap dropdown menu on a different control

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to move the dropdown menu from a bootstrap dropdown-menu to be below a different control?  (An `input` in my case.)

The dropdown is usually based off the button that causes it to dropdown.

The idea is that I have a user that is going to put a value into the input box and then press the button and there will be some floating search results in the "dropdown-menu" box that they can select from.

It will look odd for my UI to have that positioned from the button.

I can create my own popup, but I would rather just use the dropdown-menu if it supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Web page template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown"><input type="text" placeholder="blabla"></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Isn't this what you are trying to achieve or maybe I didn't understand your intentions clearly enough? You can always include any kind of element in a link tag and position your menu with CSS.

Comment: That was it exactly!  Did not know you could do that!  Thanks.